# Bootstrap MVC 4 TextBoxFor Required indicator

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am totally confused. I have 6 inputs on a page for a signup page. Three of the boxes have the required indicator in the right side of the box the other three do not. All 6 fields are required in code. [image]

I have looked through the code and either MVC is adding a background image or Bootstrap is.
Here is the Razor code I am using.

```
 <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.currentUser.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "user name", tabindex = 1 })

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.currentUser.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password", tabindex = 3 })

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.currentUser.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "last name", tabindex = 6 })

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.currentUser.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "email address", tabindex = 2 })
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.confrimPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "confirm password", tabindex = 4 })

                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.currentUser.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "first name", tabindex = 5 })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I dont have much experience with Bootstrap so I am not sure if that is what is causing the issue or if MVC is.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the model class:

```
 public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a User Name.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your last name.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email address.")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

here is the generated code for an input that has the indicator:

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a password" id="currentUser_Password" name="currentUser.Password" placeholder="password" tabindex="3" type="password" autocomplete="off" keyev="true" clickev="true" style="background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3QsPDhss3LcOZQAAAU5JREFUOMvdkzFLA0EQhd/bO7iIYmklaCUopLAQA6KNaawt9BeIgnUwLHPJRchfEBR7CyGWgiDY2SlIQBT/gDaCoGDudiy8SLwkBiwz1c7y+GZ25i0wnFEqlSZFZKGdi8iiiOR7aU32QkR2c7ncPcljAARAkgckb8IwrGf1fg/oJ8lRAHkR2VDVmOQ8AKjqY1bMHgCGYXhFchnAg6omJGcBXEZRtNoXYK2dMsaMt1qtD9/3p40x5yS9tHICYF1Vn0mOxXH8Uq/Xb389wff9PQDbQRB0t/QNOiPZ1h4B2MoO0fxnYz8dOOcOVbWhqq8kJzzPa3RAXZIkawCenHMjJN/+GiIqlcoFgKKq3pEMAMwAuCa5VK1W3SAfbAIopum+cy5KzwXn3M5AI6XVYlVt1mq1U8/zTlS1CeC9j2+6o1wuz1lrVzpWXLDWTg3pz/0CQnd2Jos49xUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=); padding-right: 0px; background-attachment: scroll; cursor: auto; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;">
```

The really weird part is I discovered that they show up in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: I cant see why you getting that, but it seems it is a glyphicon, try looking in your code for this glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk

Comment: Not that I dont trust you but can you post your model class and post the generated HTML instead of just the razor template.

Comment: Which Chrome extensions do you have? Try to check your site without any extensions. Because extensions like LastPass tend to mark input fields...

Comment: Could it be that "confrimPassword" introduces an error which breaks the bootstraps insertion of '*'? Any errors in chrome console when rendering page?

Comment: I don't think it's a Bootstrap glyphicon - that has an extra line in it (8 points rather than 6).

Comment: I do not see how you can end up with background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...); with the above code, have you extended TextBoxFor or do you have any Javascript that modifies the input to add the star or custom css behind the scene?? This does not looks like a default Bootstrap glyph indeed.

Comment: can you show your js and css ref?i think it becase some js code.if you only use bootstrap,jquery and jquery validate,it can't show any error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@nemesv - you were exactly right. LastPass is one of the extensions I had installed in Chrome. Once I disabled it the icons were removed. Pulled my hair out for days trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Yep, this is not MVC or bootstrap.